# How can I use social-auth on my templates?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I've already setup the social-auth to use Facebook and I can login now, but how to carry user data to the template? How can I use the user data on template, example:

avatar here
{{ user_city }}

Thx!

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Sure, but which one file?  Because, it's just a social-auth implementation without modifications, I just installed it and didn't make any changes. I can login now using facebook: https://dpaste.de/RRtZ

Comment: After login worked it goes to a blank page, where I hope to have something like {{ social_auth.user }}, {{ social.avatar }}, {{ social_auth.image }} or something like that (I'm not sure how to capture the user data)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to achieve this but once social_auth has been installed a user has a relationship with the `UserSocialAuth` model provided by `social_auth`. You'll have to read the [documentation](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/facebook.html) how to work with the [Facebook graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). You can ask for permissions via the [Facebook dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/).

One way:

```
{{ user.social_auth.all.0 }}  # et cetera
```

The nicer way using a templatetag and the open graph

```
<img src="{{ user|social_auth:'avatar' }}" />

@register.filter
def social_auth(user, arg):
    try:
        social_user = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user=user)
    except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
        social_user = None
    if social_user and arg == "avatar":
        return "http://graph.facebook.com/"+social_user.uid+"/picture"
```

Comment: This one looks very good, but how can I use for user birthday for example. I use this: FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'read_friendlists', 'read_stream', 'publish_actions', 'publish_stream', 'user_location', 'user_about_me' ], but how can I reach this on my template? something like {{ user.social_auth.USER_ABOUT_ME }} or similar ? Thank you in advance

Comment: These can be collected via the social auth pipeline and inserted into the `extra_data` field on the `SocialAuthUser` model (json)